# Copying my Oracle 10g Express database to another PC

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I have Oracle 10g Express. How can I make a copy of my database and application?

I don't want to make a back up, I want to move my DB and application to another PC.

Comment: the process will involve a 'backup' unless you have totally created your instance with a script. (doubtful)

Answer (score 3):

First Install XE to another PC.

Then clone your database: [Backing Up and Restoring the Database](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/backrest.htm#CHDHHEHF)

Then transfer clone to another PC and restore the clone there.

This post may help you also: [How to clone Oracle Express 10g Edition?](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=705335)

Comment: That link describes a backup (and restore) using RMAN which is probably not what the OP wants (or even understands). Using DataPump is much more approriate to copy the contents of database to a different server.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but in theory you should be able to:

1. Install the exact same version of the software on the other PC using the same installation options (same directory structure, etc).
2. Shutdown the instance on the original PC.
3. Copy all the files from the original PC to the same location on the other PC.
4. Start the instance on the other PC.

This should work for the database instance, but you may have trouble with the bundled web apps and network settings. In this case, if it's an option, you could rename your other PC to have the same name as your original PC...

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a dump of the source database using DataPump export.

Then on the target PC install Oracle XE, and use DataPump import to import the dump taken from your source PC.

For details on the DataPump utility, please see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_dp.htm

There are also various tutorials for this utility on the web, just search for "Oracle DataPump".

Using [RMAN (the "backup and recovery" tool recommended by others)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmcncpt.htm) is not a suitable tool for this kind of requirement. Doing a file level copy as suggested as well, will most probably not work either.

Comment: RMAN may not be easy to use for a beginner (particularly on XE), but it certainly is "a suitable tool for this kind of requirement"

Answer (score 0):

so what did guys is this:
I took the back up from original DB
deleted the ONLINELOG file from this bak up
replaced the entire content of this back up with those on XE file on original source
runned the restore manager and it went perfectly 
but could this make me any future errors since I messed with oracle files?

Comment: Please can you sign in on dba.se the same way you sign on to SO and get your accounts here merged, then you can edit the question or comment here.

Comment: For additional assistance on that process, you can visit this page: http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge